# Partial sum $\sum_{n=32}^{100} 5n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't remember how to find the partial sum of $$\sum_{n=32}^{100} 5n$$
I know the formula is $\frac{k}{2}\Big(a_1+a_k\Big)$ but I can't remember how to apply the formula. Thank you!

Comment: Should be the sum from 32 to 100 of 5n but I can't get it in correctly.

Comment: So $\sum\limits_{n=32}^{100}5n$?

Comment: What you do is draw  rectangle and a triangle,  duplicate it, flip one of them to make a bigger rectangle, and figure out the formula.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you!!

Comment: $a_1$ is the first term, $a_k$ the last term and $k$ the number of terms.

Answer (score 1):

A quite well known identity is
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^N n = \frac{N(N+1)}{2}. $$

So 
$$\sum\limits_{n=32}^{100}n = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{100}n - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{31}n = \frac{100\cdot 101}{2} - \frac{31\cdot 32}{2} = 4554. $$

Hence $$\sum\limits_{n=32}^{100}5n = 5\sum\limits_{n=32}^{100}n = 5\cdot 4554 = 22770.$$